# Choice operator in Haskell's parsec library

Tags: haskell, text-parsing, parsec

`Parsec` document says the following about `<|>`

> This combinator implements choice. The parser p <|> q first applies p.
>   If it succeeds, the value of p is returned. If p fails without
>   consuming any input, parser q is tried. This combinator is defined
>   equal to the mplus member of the MonadPlus class and the
>   (Control.Applicative.<|>) member of Control.Applicative.Alternative.

How to implement back-tracking version of `<|>`? It backtracks when `p` consumes any-input such the `q` can be applied to full input again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable backtracking, you simply need to use [`try`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#v%3atry), e.g. `try p <|> q`.

However, note that excessive use of `try` can hurt the performance of your parser. Consider [left factoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_factoring) your grammar instead to eliminate common prefixes where possible.